# Foundation or foundational keyboard skills?

Tags: nouns

When you learn to play a musical instrument there are some basic skills that need to be learned first.  For example, how to hold or sit at the instrument safely and comfortably; how to make the instrument sound; how to make your sounds musical (e.g. in tune, in time, staccato/legato), etc.

On the piano these essential initial skills might be called 'basic keyboard skills'.  Since they provide the foundation for subsequent learning I am inclined to call them 'foundation keyboard skills'.

But some people, when they read this have preferred to say 'foundational keyboard skills' (i.e. an adjective rather than a noun).

Is there a case that can be made for 'foundation keyboard skill' being a compound noun?

Comment: ***reading*** is a much more common word to occur between ***foundation / foundational*** and ***skills***, so check out [this usage NGram.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundational+reading+skills%2Cfoundation+reading+skills&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) I can't believe anyone would think the *meaning* is affected by whether or not you explicitly "adjectivalise" the first word by including ***-al*** (the unmodified "noun adjunct" form is a perfectly natural usage in English).

Comment: Although one might misinterpret it as skills with a foundation keyboard.  I prefer foundational.

Comment: Very helpful ngram @FumbleFingers. When *foundation skills* and *foundational skills* are compared *foundation skills* was the preferred form prior to 2005  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundational+skills%2Cfoundation+skills&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3.  The use of *foundational* seems to align with the rise of the internet!  It also seems that British English preferred *foundation* (prior to the internet!) https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundational+skills%2Cfoundation+skills&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3.

Comment: American usage only recognises *foundational*  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundational+reading+skills%2Cfoundation+reading+skills&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoundational%20reading%20skills%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Dan - I don't understand why you repeated my NGram search *without* the additional adjectival term ***reading** [skills]* to avoid "false positive" accidental matches, but I don't think it justifies saying "*foundation skills* was the preferred form prior to 2005". It's true the "bare noun adjunct" had a small increase in prevalence in the decade centred around 2010, but I'd say it was always uncommon compared to the explicitly adjectival form.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am interested to see usage for the noun or the adjectival form of 'foundation(al)'.  My three Ngrams were exploring this and suggest the adjectival form was not widely used in combination with 'skills' in the UK for a period of 20 years or so before the adjectival form (from US/internet) came to dominate... 
 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundational+skills%2Cfoundation+skills&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true

Answer (score 3):

A compound noun is usually one that has an established usage as a single term: blackboard, water fountain, etc. I therefore wouldn't describe "foundation keyboard skill" that way.

We usually prefer the adjective form if one is available. However, if the adjective's meaning is not quite right or you want to emphasize the noun, then an attributive noun is often fine.

For example, it might be possible to say that an engineering firm that builds foundations for buildings does "foundational construction", but most people would prefer "foundation construction".

In your case, the adjective "foundational" seems to work well, and I don't see any need to emphasize the fact that the skills have to do with a "foundation", so I agree with the people who prefer the adjective form. [This Google Books ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=foundational%20reading%20skills%2Cfoundation%20reading%20skills&year_start=1960&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfoundational%20reading%20skills%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfoundation%20reading%20skills%3B%2Cc0) (from FumbleFingers' comment, with "reading" instead of "keyboard") supports that idea:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you mean to say, we prefer the *adjectival* form if one is available :P

Comment: @YaakovSaxon Oh haha, yes, I guess I used "adjective" itself as an attributive noun there!

Comment: @MarcInManhattan what is your reason and basis for saying that '...we usually prefer the adjective form if one is available...'?  You didn't!

Comment: @Dan I admit that I don't think I could quickly find an authoritative source for that. However, I don't think there's any dispute that adjectives usually modify nominals, whereas nominals usually have other functions (as subject, as direct object, etc.). So I think that common sense suggests that an adjective is preferable when modifying a nominal.